# Execute a shell program by clicking a link in a web page. Language : Python

Tags: php, python, html, shell, cgi

My requirment is to create a .py code to open a webpage with links. On clicking each link should execute a shell program(not single command).

Following is my work. I decided to go with CGI.The problem is I cant able to execute .sh file onclicking the link, hence i tried php code there.

Any command inside php code is also not working, even a simple alert().

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb
import sys
import os
import webbrowser

try:

 <<<<some sql process >>>>

 print 'Content-Type: text/html'
 print
 print '<html>'
 print '<head><title>Zenoss Monitoring</title>'
 print '<script>'
 print 'function invokescript()'
 print '{'
 print '<?php'
 print '  exec("./Script1.sh",$out,$return);'
 print '  alert("2");'
 print '?>'
 print 'alert("2");'
 print 'return;'
 print '}'
 print '</script>'
 print '</head><body>'

 print '<button type="button" onclick="invokescript()">Script 1</button>'

 print '</br></body></html>'

 webbrowser.open("http://192.168.1.205/cgi-bin/sql5.py")

except MySQLdb.Error, e:

 print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])
 sys.exit(1)
```

Help me to resolve this.

Orelse if there is any other better way to acheive my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP is supposed to be executed on the server-side. If you want to do something on the server-side from the client-side, you need to make a request. Use javascript to give requests, and let a PHP or Python script handle it.

Comment: First you should try to understand how web apps work, what is the difference between client side and server side execution, what language is used for what etc. Right now you just mixed things up and hoped it will work, but you are far from it.